# Suggested edit after a retag within 5 minute grace period

Tags: support, tags, edits, suggested-edits, grace-period

What actually happen when you suggest an edit just after a retag?

I did that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077475/is-it-okay-to-add-id-class-to-link-tag), and now I am worried about the outcome.

Will they merge into a single edit? Is there a possibility that the retagging have no effect in case of an unapproved edit?

Comment: Link to the question please.

Comment: @Oded link added

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. It's not within the 5 minute grace period now. But I'm not sure what would happen if the edit got approved within the 5 minute grace period of a retag.