# Don't allow edit suggestion during grace period

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I just edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460239/use-todictionary-to-create-a-dictionary/14460309#14460309) that contained some code that was overall neat and correct, but wouldn't compile. I made it compile clean and (in my opinion) more readable.

The edit got rejected as too minor, because during my edit the OP made the code compile-clean in the grace period and thus in the diff that shows up to the reviewers, only the parts making the code more readable showed up. Such an edit is a too minor one, without question.

In my opinion there are two possibilities to solve this kind of "conflict":

- When user A has edited a post and user B (>2k rep, or original author) has edited that post in the meantime user A gets a message that the post has changed and is asked to revise that edit based on the changes made in the meantime.
- The easier one: Don't allow edit suggestions in the grace period.

I don't care about the missing reputation I would have gotten if the suggestion had been approved. I just don't like my suggestions being reviewed on a false basis - because the diff that is displayed to the approvers does not display the correct edit.

Doing a quick search here on meta I found some questions maybe related to this problem - none of them however addresses the problem of the review based on incorrect diffs:

- [No warning when OP edits question during the five minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100003/no-warning-when-op-edits-question-during-the-five-minute-grace-period)
- [Question history attributed changes to me that I didn't make](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make)
- [Suggested edit after a retag within 5 minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128734/suggested-edit-after-a-retag-within-5-minute-grace-period)

Comment: I just got bit by this, but with a worse effect.  I describe it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193290/possible-bug-with-edit-submission/193294?noredirect=1#193294), but basically I edited a question apparently at the same time as the OP.  Weird part is that on the Suggestion page, it appears as though what I was suggesting for an edit was actually the original text.  So I agree with the first suggestion above -- warn me if an edit has been applied before mine is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

It'd probably be best just to let any editors know that someone else is editing the question, though it's no perfect solution, since sometimes someone could click into 'edit mode' and then get distracted and not get it finished.

The problem with not allowing edits in the grace period is that posts need to get cleaned up as soon as possible to give them a better chance to live and get answers.  Still it's not that long a period of time, and would only have trouble on Stack Overflow itself, with it's question rate.

Comment: *someone could click into 'edit mode' and then get distracted and not get it finished* There could be a detection of activity on the client side + timeout on the server. For example client would report edit activity every two minutes and when there is no activity for four minutes the client would be notified and in one following minute the edit would be automatically postponed.