# Possible bug with edit submission

Tags: bug, review, edits

I proposed an edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240240/msaccess-minimize-the-toolbar-ribbon-onload), and my edit was rejected.

I'm not contesting the rejection, but something appears screwy.  When I first saw the question, there was no code formatting.  So I clicked "Edit", added the code formatting and clicked "Save Edits".  I got a message saying that my edit was less than six characters, so I made another slight change (added the second "I" in "I realize I can totally").  Hit "Save Edits" again and got the Thank You message.

Now, when I click on the "suggested edit" link for the question (in my Activity list), what appears for both the original text and my edited text are very different from what I saw when I made the the edit.  The original text has the code formatted, and my edited text includes a number of spelling and grammar changes that I did not make.  Also, the "original" text matches what the question *currently* looks like.

Only thing I can think of is that the OP edited his own question at the same time I was doing the same, and that his edit and mine were swapped, with my change being applied as if it was his.

Bug?  Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: [This suggestion?](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2722679)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [five minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20441/192187) for the poster to edit their question before the edits are recorded in the edit log. Looks like the OP edited it barely within the five minutes so no edit is shown in the edit log.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense.  But it should prevent me from submitting an edit in that case; as it is, it appears that the original text was my submitted edit.

Comment: There's a feature request for that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164610/192187).