# Difference in edit and actual review

Tags: bug, review, questions, edits, suggested-edits

When I edited the code the OP has not posted some part of code, however in the review part OP's edited code is displayed.

Obviously my edit will not be approved as I'm missing some part of OP code(That was not posted earlier).

I'm not sure if it is a bug! However with out adding bug tag I wasn't allowed to proceed to submit.

Any idea why this happened?

**How long should I wait (minimum time) before editing any new post?**

**Also, how can I edit the post again which is currently under review, once I found that it is missing some part?**

**My edit:**

[image: My edit]

**My post in suggested edit**

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164610/dont-allow-edit-suggestion-during-grace-period et al. You've been bitten by a grace-period edit.

Comment: @mmyers: Thanks for the link. Is there a way by which I can edit my post again once I found that it is missing some section?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; you can always edit your own posts unless they're locked.

Comment: @mmyers: Sorry for the confusion, I mean is there a way by which I can edit the post  which is currently under review.

Comment: You mean edit your suggestion before it is approved? Last I checked I was able to do so.

Comment: @mmyers: Kindly suggest how? That will be very helpful.

Comment: I just tried on [Puzzling.SE]. All I had to do was click the edit button again. However, I don't know how the post would appear to me if it had been edited by someone else before I submitted my edit.

Comment: @mmyers: Thanks a lot :)